# Como faço para adicionar a API Firebase ao meu projeto android?

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Estava pesquisando sobre e achei bastante interessante, mas não sei o que é necessário e como fazer para usar

Answer (score 1):

Se for no Android Studio, é necessario no minimo um dispositivo com Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) ou versões
mais recente, e o Google Play Services 15.0.0 ou superior. Te indico entrar nesse link da documentação oficial do Firebase
com o tutorial completo
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup